# Selecting rows on value change

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stock index table named 'snp250' as

```
No    Date        Open       High     Low      Close       Difference
5061  2015-03-31  8527.60    8550.45  8454.15  8491.00     -1.30
5060  2015-03-30  8390.95    8504.55  8380.75  8492.30     150.90
5059  2015-03-27  8396.00    8413.20  8269.15  8341.40     -0.75
5058  2015-03-26  8474.95    8499.45  8325.35  8342.15     -188.65
```

till

```
5041  2015-03-02  8953.85    8972.35  8885.45  8956.75     54.90
```

Few things-
1. Date is unique but not always consecutive like it skips the weekend dates.
2. No is unique and always consecutive.

I want query records where the difference changes from negative to positive. so the queries fetches record earlier to which difference changes.

My current sql -

```
select t1.* 
from snp250 as t1, snp250 as t2 
where(t1.no_id = t2.no_id+1) 
AND((t1.difference>=0 AND t2.difference<0) 
OR (t1.difference<0 AND t2.difference>0)).
```

The problem here is the queries skips the 1st record.

I tried another sql -

```
select t1.* 
from snp250 as t1, snp250 as t2 
where(t1.no_id = t2.no_id-1) 
AND((t1.difference>=0 AND t2.difference<0) 
 OR (t1.difference<0 AND t2.difference>0)).
```

But here it skips the last record.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: So you want to select records such that the difference changes sign *relative to the previous entry's difference* or relative to the difference of either of the entries surrounding the current entry? If the first, then your first query should be fine, because in that case it *makes sense* to skip the first record, since there is no way to compare it to anything,

Comment: Means only those 2 records where your difference goes from the negative value to positive value??

Comment: @MichaelTontchev - Technically even the 1st row should be displayed. If the 1st row is negative and 2nd is positive, it needs to show the 1st row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - mysql with xampp

Comment: So let me get this straight: if, for a given row r, row r+1 has a difference with the opposite sign as row r, you want the query to return row r, or row r+1?

Comment: @MichaelTontchev I am select the table as two alias t1 & t2 where i fetch records of table t1 by comparing difference column of each table based on the criteria that no of t1 is greater then no of t2 by 1. Hence t1.no starts from 2. I would like to start it from 1 rather.

Comment: I understand that, Nitesh - I'm asking this: when you compare row r to row r+1, if difference changes from positive to negative, do you want the query to return row r, or row r+1? Example:

row1: difference = 50
row2: difference = -10
row3: difference = -20
row4: difference = 60

What rows do you want returned? Rows 1 and 2?

Comment: @MichaelTontchev It should return row 1, row2 and row 4.

Comment: Why should row 1 and 2 both be returned? Row 1 is returned because the next row is negative. But the same isn't true for row 2: the row after row 2 is not positive. It seems like you're trying to use different criteria for different rows.

Answer (score 0):

The following query uses a correlated subquery to get the previous value:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.difference
        from snp250 t2
        where t2.date < t.date
        order by t2.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_difference
from snp250 t
```

To get the rows where the difference changes, then you can use a MySQL extension to the `having` clause, by appending:

```
having prev_difference < 0 and difference > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
  select * from snp250 t1 where (select (t1.difference*t2.difference) from    snp250  t2 where t2.no_id=t1.no_id+1)<0
```

This query will be true only if there is no condition on the sign change in difference column. It may be from +ve to -ve or -ve to +ve.